# When is $ \int_{B(0;1)}{ 1 \over ∣x∣^{n} }$ is finite in $R^d$?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

Is $$ \int_{B(0;1)}{ 1 \over ∣x∣^{n−2} }$$ is finite for $n > 2$ ?  Can we conclude this from local integrability of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{∣x∣^{n−2}}$?

I needed this in [when is : $\int_{R^n\backslash\{0\}}|{f(x) \over |x|^{n-2}}| dx < \infty$ given $f$ is summable and continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850243/when-is-int-rn-backslash-0-fx-over-xn-2-dx-infty-given)

Comment: $B(0,1)$ in what space? Some power of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry. It is some power of R.

Comment: Well one obvious thing I can say is that the integral with $n \geq 3$ is not integrable in $\mathbb{R}^1$ so cannot be in higher dimensions.

Comment: Not just any power, in the other question, $n$ was the dimension of the space. If we decouple the dimension and exponent, the integral is finite whenever the dimension of the space is $> (n-2)$.

Comment: As long as $n<k+2$ when we are in $\mathbb{R}^k,$ what you have is integrable.

Comment: So if dimension of the space is $n$ it is not integrable right ?

Comment: Since $n > n-2$, it is then (locally) integrable. It would also be locally integrable in all higher dimensions, and in dimension $n-1$, but not in smaller dimensions.

Comment: can you write it down in detail so that it becomes clear and  i can accept it as an answer ?

Comment: user2493027 already has the essentials covered in his/her answer. Would you need much more details added? Otherwise, I think he/she would be happy to fill in a couple of details.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have some doubts in that answer.Also it would be nice if you can expand on the points involving non-integer exponents and local-integrability making the answer much more comprehensive in the interest of everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote the dimension of the space by $d$. Then the Jacobian determinant of the polar/spherical coordinate change contains a factor $r^{d-1}$ (times some sines or cosines of the angles). If we integrate a rotationally invariant function, i.e., we can write $f(x) = g(\lvert x\rvert)$, for a function $g\colon (0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, then introducing polar/spherical coordinates gives

$$\int_{a < \lvert x\rvert < b} f(x)\,dx = \omega_{d-1}\int_a^b g(r)r^{d-1}\,dr,\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_{d-1}$ is the $d-1$-dimensional volume of the unit sphere $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d : \lvert x\rvert = 1\}$. Note that $\omega_{d-1}\cdot r^{d-1}$ is the area of the $d-1$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$, so

$$\omega_{d-1}g(r)r^{d-1} = \int_{\lvert x\rvert = r} g(\lvert x\rvert)\,dS(x) = \int_{\lvert x\rvert = r} f(x)\,dS(x),$$

where $dS$ denotes the $d-1$-dimensional surface measure on the sphere, so $(1)$ transforms the $d$-dimensional integral into an iterated integration, much like one does for integrals over products of intervals.

If we look in particular at functions of the form $f_\alpha\colon x \mapsto \frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^\alpha}$, we see that - for $0 < a < b < \infty$ - we have

$$\int_{a < \lvert x\rvert < b} f_\alpha(x)\,dx = \omega_{d-1} \int_a^b \frac{r^{d-1}}{r^\alpha}\,dr = \int_a^b r^{d-1-\alpha}\,dr = \begin{cases} \omega_{d-1} \log \frac{b}{a} &, \alpha = d\\ \dfrac{\omega_{d-1}}{d-\alpha}\left(b^{d-\alpha} - a^{d-\alpha}\right) &, \alpha\neq d.\end{cases}$$

From that we read off that the integral remains bounded as $a\to 0$ (for $b$ fixed) if and only if $\alpha < d$, since then $a^{d-\alpha} \to 0$, while $a^{d-\alpha}\to\infty$ for $a\to 0$ if $\alpha > d$, and also $\log \frac{b}{a}\to \infty$ for $a\to 0$ for the case of equality.

On the other hand, for $b\to\infty$ with a fixed $a$, the integral remains bounded if and only if $\alpha > d$.

So we have, that for arbitrary $R \in (0,\infty)$

$$\int_{\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^d :\lvert x\rvert < R\}} \frac{dx}{\lvert x\rvert^\alpha} < \infty \iff \alpha < d$$

and

$$\int_{\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^d :\lvert x\rvert > R\}} \frac{dx}{\lvert x\rvert^\alpha} < \infty \iff \alpha > d.$$

Answer (score 1):

Expressing the integral in polar coordinates (and setting $k\equiv 2-n$)
$$ \int_{B^d(0,1)}\vert x\vert^k \mathrm{dx} = C_d\int_{0}^1r^{k+d-1}\mathrm{dr}$$
where $C_d$ is a finite constant depending on the dimension [It is the surface area of the $d$-dimensional unit-sphere]. The Jacobian of the polars introduces the extra $r^{d-1}$.
For the integral to exist, the overall exponent cannot be negative, so $k+d-1=d-n+1\geq 0$ is required.

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course, thank you. Corrected. Embarassing...

Comment: In the last line, it's the same for integer exponents, but if we allow non-integer exponents, the condition is $k+d-1 > -1$, that may be worth an explicit mention.

Comment: @user2493027 have we substituted  $ k = 2-n $ or $k = n-2 $?

Comment: Good point, @SrinivasK, sign change in the exponent. $k = 2-n$ is the correct choice, leading to $2-n+d-1 > -1$, or equivalently $d > n-2$.

Comment: @SrinivasK Yeah, sorry again. $k=2-n$ Maybe I should refrain from doing math today, i'm obviously very sloppy.